# import media does not work in Python

Tags: python

I am reading a book about python. There is a sample. The first line is:

```
import media
```

I am trying to do the same, but the error like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import media
ImportError: No module named media
```

I want to know, is the media a default library?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using [this book](http://pragprog.com/titles/gwpy/practical-programming) (mentioning it specifically would have made it easier to identify than just saying "a book", BTW;-).  Per [this thread](https://csc.cdf.toronto.edu/bb/YaBB.pl?num=1253052310/0), you need to install some modules as documented [here](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/fall/python.shtml), and possibly the [pygraphics](http://code.google.com/p/pygraphics/) package.  Doesn't the book itself explain that, in an introduction or maybe in an appendix?

Comment: Reading is hard (oh the irony...).

Answer (score 1):

[Absolutely not](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/pygraphics/wiki/MacInstall

PyGraphics (which includes the 'media' module) installs via the package included with the code for the Practical Programming book but isn't currently usable on OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard